# Geometric changes

Tags: differential-geometry

I want to find the coordinate of point on filament yarn after receiving some force or heat .
please help me !

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but too long for a comment:

Assuming that the axis of the yarn is the $z$-axis, the helix in question lies on a cylinder of radius $r$ and meets the plane $z = 0$ at angle $\theta_0$ from the positive $x$-axis, and successive "turns" of a filament are separated by distance $k$ along the axis, the coordinates of points on the helix may be written in terms of a real parameter $\theta$ as
$$
x = r\cos(\theta + \theta_0),\qquad
y = r\sin(\theta + \theta_0),\qquad
z = k\theta/(2\pi).
$$
In your diagram, $2\pi r/k = \tan\alpha$, i.e., $k = 2\pi r \cot\alpha$.

However, this seems unlikely to answer your question fully; you need to provide information on exactly how force and/or heat affect the yarn. (For example, applying tension along the yarn decreases both $\alpha$ and $r$, probably in a complicated way. The details constitute a mathematical model of your yarn.)

Comment: thank you so much !
the force ( heat ) cause length of yarn decrease and point get closer to center .
in this formula , I need to use shrinkage factor of yarn and other factors .
you can use this paper :
http://anonymousdelivers.us/133155/6a67037efd5188bcced2a62f79984e68